# How to add a ionic v3 component in ion-content but put the component's child button in ion-footer

Tags: ionic-framework

I’ve created a few components that handle form submission functionality. In each of these components, I want the form submit/cancel buttons to be fixed at the bottom of the view, much like the functionality available via ion-footer. The submit button needs reference to the variables + methods in the component for [disabled] + (tap) functionality, for example [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" (tap)="submitForm()"

If the component is a child of ion-content then there is no way to add ion-footer as it will be contained within ion-content, instead of below ion-content. At first glance, having ion-footer inside ion-content appears to view properly, but the rendering can be buggy especially in scroll situations. I went as far as setting a force-bottom css class with fixed position/bottom but it looks like the ionic javascript overrides fixed positioning when inside ion-content, so a pure CSS solution does not seem to be possible.

```
<ion-content> 
    <a-form-component>
    </a-form-component>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <!-- add a-form-component's button here -->
</ion-footer>
```

Any recommendations on how to achieve the desired functionality?

TIA

Comment: if your goal is just to put the button at the bottom of the page then you can do it with pure css.

Comment: George, thanks for the reply. The pure CSS doesn't work. Anything inside of ion-content moves with the scroll. I tried fixed positioning bottom:0, left:0 with height. No dice when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a page called `page` and a component called `cp`
inside `page.html` you have the component `<cp></cp>`

Inside `cp.html` you have

```
<div>anything goes here</div>
<div>anything goes here</div>
<div>anything goes here</div>
<div>anything goes here</div>
<div id="the-footer">
    <button>login<button>
</div>
```

inside `page.scss`:

```
  #the-footer{

         background-color: #efefef;
         text-align: center;
         position: fixed;
         width: 100%;
         bottom: 0px;
         z-index: 99999;
  }
```

This will achieve the same result as ion-footer.

The div containing the button will always be visible regardless of the scrolling.

hope it helps